# Static directory at the top level of the drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, performance, filesystems, file-management

On my Windows desktop, I need some directory which must stay on the same place "forever".

It is itended primarly for images, which sometimes included into Markdown files. Here is how it works:

```
C:\Users\John\Desktop\Some Project\
                       |-- My Document.md

                           Which looks like this:
                            -----------------------
                           | My Document.md        |
                           |                       |
                           | Some text...          |
                           |                       |
                           | ![](C:\Static\foo.jpg |
                           |                       |
                           | Some text...          |
                           |                       |
                           | ![](C:\Static\bar.jpg |
                           |                       |
                           | Some text...          |
                           |                       |
                           | ![](C:\Static\baz.jpg |
                           |                       |
                            -----------------------
```

So, instead of keeping images in the same folder with document, I keep them in "Static". This allows me to use same images across multiple documents without duplicating.

However, when I studied in the university (few years ago), the teacher said something that **could** be related to my idea:

> When you put some file in the root directory of the drive, it will speed up access to this file. However, when you have **too many** files in the root directory, the **overall work** of hard drive will be slowler.

But, I don't sure this quote is **really** related to my idea, because it seems a little difference between it and what my teacher said:

```
Teacher said     My idea
C:\foo.jpg       C:\Static\foo.jpg
C:\bar.jpg       C:\Static\bar.jpg
C:\baz.jpg       C:\Static\baz.jpg
etc              etc
```

So, my question:

Is it really related? I.e. is it a good idea (from the hard drive performace point of view) to keep thousands of images in C:\Static?

Or, probably, it will be better to keep them in %UserProfile%\Static?

Some technical notes:

- I use hard drive, i.e. HDD, not SSD. The performance probably could be different.
- As I said, I use Windows, and that means, my file system is NTFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You add only one record to root directory - "Static". So it not noticeable impact performance.
2. NTFS lesser impact on performance from too many files in directory (AFAIK directory indexed in NTFS).

**UPD**

3. %UserProfile%\Static can be preferred for public distribution. As any unprivileged user can write there and create folders and files. Root folder can be not accessible. (As I understand it not Your case)
4. If there really Huge amount of files (thousands) is better to distribute it by subdirectories (eg. Static/foo/foo0001.jpg ... Static/foo/foo1000.jpg, Static/bar/bar0001.jpg ... Static/bar/bar1000.jpg, ...)